# Resize Canvas html to fit the inner content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to record audio and draw the bars on canvas. But I am stuck on resizing the canvas according to the length of bars that are there. Following is the JS for all the work that is being done. I tried adding function to resize canvas, and override the canvas width but none is working.
css width:auto; is also not working. Following is the function That I have used to resize canvas according the to BARS length that are drawn.
I tried to override the canvas width inside stop function [Current Visual of Bars inside canvas][1]

Following code can be tested in this codepen https://codepen.io/smashingmag/pen/qBVzRaj

```
function resizeCanvas() {
    CANVAS.width = BARS.length;
  console.log(CANVAS.width);
  }
resizeCanvas();
```

```js
//Getting and initializing canvas from html to create bars 
    const CANVAS = document.querySelector('canvas')
    const DRAWING_CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext('2d')
```

```js
//setting canvas height and width and bars configuration
    CANVAS.width = CANVAS.offsetWidth
    CANVAS.height = CANVAS.offsetHeight
    
    const CONFIG = {
      fft: 2048,
      show: true,
      duration: 0.8,
      fps: 100,
      barWidth: 0.1,
      barMinHeight: 0.01,
      barMaxHeight: 0.3,
      barGap: 0.01,
    }
```

```js
//here I am creating bars
const addBar = (volume = 100) => {
  const BAR = {
    x: CANVAS.width + CONFIG.barWidth / 2,
    // Note the volume is 0
    size: gsap.utils.mapRange(
      50,
      150,
      CANVAS.height * CONFIG.barMinHeight/3,
      CANVAS.height * CONFIG.barMaxHeight*3
    )(volume),
  }
const drawBars = () => {
  DRAWING_CONTEXT.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height)
  for (const BAR of BARS) {
    drawBar(BAR)
  }
}

STOP.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (recorder) recorder.stop()
  AUDIO.setAttribute('controls', true)
  AUDIO_CONTEXT.close()
  timeline.pause()
  SCRUB(START_POINT)
  var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

setTimeout(function() {
  //Here i am getting the canvas image on console
  

  const img =  CANVAS.toDataURL("image/png");  
console.log(img);
}, delayInMilliseconds);
})

drawBars()
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBBjT.png

Comment: that's a lot of code to go through, can you provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem?

Comment: Check it now @Matthias

Comment: that's much better, but it's still missing some code relevant to your question I think. For example, where is BARS defined? Might be a good idea to show the html/css code as well (just the minimal). And what do those console logs print?

Comment: @Matthias I have added the whole JS code and CSS code. Console to logs are just for testing the values. But for more clarity you can paste the above code in the provided codepen link.

Comment: okay, now we have the same problem as in the beginning, I should have linked this, take a look at this, see if you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Matthias I hope the above code is more readable now. I have added few snippets where the bars were being created along with some comments

Comment: there's still a lot of code you could have skipped, I believe the only relevant code is CANVAS.width = "" and the css code. But I suppose it's hard to know that, I'm going to post an answer which I hope will be a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your codepen and I think yours has a simple solution

```
function resizeCanvas() {
    CANVAS.style.width = BARS.length + "px";
    CANVAS.width = BARS.length;
}
```

This is just setting the CSS `width` property using javascript.

Doing `CANVAS.width = 500` does not overwrite the CSS which tells it to be `300px`. So it was still a CSS problem.

Comment: If we do CANVAS.width=BARS.length; inside STOP function, The width gets overwritten

Comment: then there's probably some code there which redraws or does something with the canvas, you might have to call that code again after `resizeCanvas()`